# Remove double-double quotes in a string in C

Tags: c

I have the string below which i have tried to remove one of the double quotes.

```
MSNT_SystemTrace,RecvIPV4,FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF,0,2,0,,,,0,0x0,"[2]FFFFFFFF.FFFFFFFF::07/02/2022-10:32:37.367 [MSNT_SystemTrace]{""PID"":9104,""size"":361,""daddr"":""52.149.21.60"",""saddr"":""192.168.1.52"",""dport"":443,""sport"":51799,""seqnum"":0,""meta"":{""provider"":""MSNT_SystemTrace"",""event"":""RecvIPV4"",""time"":""2022-07-02T10:32:37.367"",""cpu"":2,""task"":""TcpIp""}}"
```

```
{""PID"":9104,""size"":361,""daddr"":""52.149.21.60"",""saddr"":""192.168.1.52"",""dport"":443,""sport"":51799,""seqnum"":0,""meta"":{""provider"":""MSNT_SystemTrace"",""event"":""RecvIPV4"",""time"":""2022-07-02T10:32:37.367"",""cpu"":2,""task"":""TcpIp""}}"
```

Here is my code;

```
char* newString;
int i, j;
if (substring[0] != '"')
    newString[0] = substring[0];
for (i = j = 1; i < strlen(substring); i++) {
    if (substring[i] == '"')
        continue;
    newString[j++] = substring[i];
}
```

But what i end up getting is a string without any of the quotes like the one below;

```
{PID:9104,size:361,daddr:52.149.21.60,saddr:192.168.1.52,dport:443,sport:51799,seqnum:0,meta:{provider:MSNT_SystemTrace,event:RecvIPV4,time:2022-07-02T10:32:37.367,cpu:2,task:TcpIp}}
```

The string below is what i want to achieve, how can i go about this?

```
{"PID":9104,"size":361,"daddr":"52.149.21.60","saddr":"192.168.1.52","dport":443,"sport":51799,"seqnum":0,"meta":{"provider":"MSNT_SystemTrace","event":"RecvIPV4","time":"2022-07-02T10:32:37.367","cpu":2,"task":"TcpIp"}}
```

Comment: And where is there your code?

Comment: I don't see a string but something syntactically invalid.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: What do you want your program to do when it encounters a single double-quote? Or is it guaranteed that double-quotes will only occur in groups of two?

Comment: Where do you take that string from ? 
Notice that if you declare and initialize something like `char substring[20] = "{""PID"":9104}"` and then you try to `printf("%s", substring);` what you'll get is `{PID:9104}`

Hope this clarify :)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i want the program to eliminate the double quotes i.e from ""PID"":9104 to "PID":9104

Comment: @robkims: Your previous comment does not answer my question.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel actually i want the double-quotes to occur in groups of two only.

Comment: It makes no sense to call `strlen` in the loop test.  That turns an O(n) loop into an O(n^2) loop.  You wouldn't do it that way by hand, so why would you write code that does?  Bad code.

Comment: I have added the raw string  that actually i want to extract everything from the start of curly braces until the end of the string. Then convert it to json object that enable me write to a database. That is my general idea.

Comment: The computer has done exactly what you told it to do. You told it to copy all the letters except the quotes. Can you figure out how to tell it to copy all the letters but if there are two quotes in a row then copy one quote instead?

Comment: @robkims: So the code that you are writing is allowed to assume that if it encounters a double-quote character, then the next character will also be a double-quote? In that case, when you encounter a double-quote in the source string, you can simply skip two characters and write a single double-quote to the target string. Note, however, that if this assumption cannot be relied upon, then your program may crash in cases where this assumption is false.

Comment: After your most recent edit to your question, the question has become more unclear. In your question, you refer to "the string below", but after your most recent edit, you now specify two code snippets with two strings. So now it is unclear what "the string below" refers to. Please edit your question to clarify this.

Comment: I hope you are aware you must initialize `newString` before doing anything like `newString[0]`.

Comment: If you don't mind a bit of code obfuscation, then this could suffice: `void dedup(char *t, const char *s) { while (s+=*s=='"', *t++=*s++); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check the current character for a double quote and jump accordingly, in order to get what you want, you must also check the next character:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char *substring = "{\"\"PID\"\":9104,\"\"size\"\":361,\"\"daddr\"\":\"\"52.149.21.60\"\",\"\"saddr\"\":\"\"192.168.1.52\"\",\"\"dport\"\":443,\"\"sport\"\":51799,\"\"seqnum\"\":0,\"\"meta\"\":{\"\"provider\"\":\"\"MSNT_SystemTrace\"\",\"\"event\"\":\"\"RecvIPV4\"\",\"\"time\"\":\"\"2022-07-02T10:32:37.367\"\",\"\"cpu\"\":2,\"\"task\"\":\"\"TcpIp\"\"}}";

    int i, j = 0, len = strlen(substring);
    char* newString = (char*)malloc(len+1);

    if (newString == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
    {
        if (substring[i] == '"' && i + 1 < len && substring[i + 1] == '"')
            continue;

        newString[j++] = substring[i];
    }


    newString[j] = '\0';    
    printf("%s\n", newString);

    free(newString);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. This code will remove all consecutive double-quotes and leave only one instead. But from your question, I believe your goal is to get a valid JSON string, so it should be fine.

Comment: If there are four consecutive double quotes in the input, I believe you end up with one in the output whereas two would be expected.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, you are right, but according to the question, there are no four consecutive double quotes. Also, I forgot to null terminate the output buffer, and anyway I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I just realized that author of the question is trying to get a valid JSON string as output, so removing all consecutive double quotes and leaving only one instead should be fine.

Comment: @SunDro this works fine. I can now proceed.

Answer (score 2):

When you encounter a double quote, you'll need to check whether the next character is also a double quote or not. This implementation will skip all but the last one from any number of consecutive double quotes, not just 2.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char* substring = "{\"\"PID\"\":9104,\"\"size\"\":361,\"\"daddr\"\":\"\"52.149.21.60\"\",\"\"saddr\"\":\"\"192.168.1.52\"\"}";
    int length = strlen(substring);
    int new_index = 0;
    
    char* new_string = calloc(length + 1, sizeof(char));
    if (new_string == NULL) exit(1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (substring[i] == '"' && substring[i + 1] == '"') continue;
        new_string[new_index++] = substring[i];
    }
    
    printf("%s\n", new_string);
    // {"PID":9104,"size":361,"daddr":"52.149.21.60","saddr":"192.168.1.52"}
    
    free(new_string);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the double quotes need to be escaped (`\"`) for this to work, otherwise each pair of double quotes just signifies a new string, such that `"{""PID"` is the same as `"{"` and `"PID"`.

Comment: When `i` is zero and the string starts with a double quote, you access the array out of bounds.  I would expect to look at the next character rather than the previous one.

Comment: Indeed, I'll update my answer!

Comment: @rhelminen, okay your solution works quite well, then how is it possible to add the escape character if the 'substring' is a variable string i get from a server?

Comment: `substring` itself should already be escaped after you have read it from your input source. How to do that depends on your implementation of analyzing the input, but that's a whole different question altogether. Regarding `new_string` in my example, [calloc](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) will initialize all the allocated bits to zero, so you won't need to manually terminate the string, like you would with `malloc`.